# How should I go about introducing variables that I would like to be in a definition and be global at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to make two functions. One receives an input named `get_guess`, and the other, `update_dashes,` calculates the the indices at which that letter appears in a predetermined word and places dashes/the letter in a string.

Here's my code:

```
secret_word = 'tracy'
dashes = ""
def get_guess(guess):
    while True:
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "Your guess must be exactly one character!"
        elif not guess.islower():
            print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
        else:
            break
        guess = input("Guess: ")
    return guess

def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        if secret_word[i] == guess:
            dashes += guess
        else:
            dashes += "-"


while True:
    update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess)
    print dashes
    if get_guess(guess) in secret_word:
        print "That letter is in the secret word!"
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the secret word!"
```

How can I adjust the calling of these functions so that I don't get a "`guess` is not defined", while keeping my code relatively clean with two functions?

Comment: What are you wanting `guess` to be when `update_dashes` is called? Why not just call `get_guess` before the loop or something and get a guess?

Comment: Get rid of the argument passed to `get_guess()` and change it so it returns the value. In the `while` loop, do `guess = get_guess()` _before_ calling `update_dashes(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat a little bit your code like this :

```py
secret_word = 'tracy'
dashes = ""

def get_guess(): # <=== no variable needed as this function will generate a guess based on user input
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess: ")
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print "Your guess must be exactly one character!"
        elif not guess.islower():
            print "Your guess must be a lowercase letter!"
        else:
            break
    return guess

def update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess):
    for letter in secret_word:
        if letter == guess:
            dashes += guess
        else:
            dashes += "-"
     return dashes  #<======= Return you dashes updated


while True:
    dashes = update_dashes(secret_word, dashes, guess)
    print dashes
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess in secret_word:
        print "That letter is in the secret word!"
    else:
        print "That letter is not in the secret word!"
```

Is it intened that your code is writen for python 2 ?

Comment: running this code results in an UnboundLocalError, where `guess` is referenced before assignment on line 6